# How can you add an USB OTG port to the average mainboard?

Tags: linux, usb, hardware

OTG ports are mostly used on ARM devices like smartphones or single board computers. 
Is there some way to add this functionality to the average desktop or laptop mainboard? There are addon cards like pci-usb adapters but these don't provide OTG. But maybe there are other devices which do. Or is it generally impossible to add OTG to those mainboards?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft Windows supports acting as an USB *peripheral* (as opposed to being an USB *host*), so hardware manufacturers won't expect to see much demand for USB OTG functionality on desktops or laptops. On the other hand, USB Type-C includes functionality equivalent to OTG (now known as *dual-role data ports*). What are you actually trying to achieve with OTG ports on a desktop/laptop?

Comment: I'd like to use them as gadget devices but I'd like to include everything in a mainboard with a decent CPU and memory. Sure I could use an RPI zero and the likes but this is slow and also adds another device including peripherals, gets more complicated... I'd like to have everything in one device. Thinking about it, it looks like OTG is more of a CPU feature and not related to other stuff. Dunno if there are dedicated USB controllers/chips which support OTG.